# How to make two submenu in sidebar

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-mobile-navbar

I want to create 2 submenus when the menu in the sidebar is clicked

Here what i've done

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[data-toggle]").click(function () {
        var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
        $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
    });
    $('.parent').click(function () {
        $('.submenu').toggle('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition:  right 0.4s ease-in-out;  

}

.container.open-sidebar {
    right: 240px;
}


#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    right: -240px;
    background: #DF314D;  
    width: 240px;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;

}

#sidebar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}


#sidebar ul li {
    margin: 0;

}
#sidebar ul li a {

    padding: 15px 20px 15px 35px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #C9223D;

    -webkit-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:  background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}


#sidebar li:hover { 

    background: #C9223D;
    border-radius: 4px;
}


.main-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.main-content .content{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 60px;
    width: 100%;
}
.main-content .content h1{
    font-weight: 100;
}
.main-content .content p{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 160%;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle {
    background: #DF314D;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 7px;
    float: right;
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;   
}
.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
     margin-bottom: 0;   
}

.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar{
    display: block;
    width: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 3px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;   
}

.main-content #sidebar-toggle .bar:last-child{
     margin-bottom: 0;   
}


.menu a.home {

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bpi.png) no-repeat 4px 10px;


 }

.menu a.explore { 

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/gasi.png) no-repeat 4px 10px;
 }

.menu a.users { 

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bicici.png) no-repeat 4px 10px; 
}

.menu a.signout { 

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bai.png) no-repeat 4px 10px; 
}


#sidebar .menu .submenu {
    display: none;

}


#sidebar ul li ul.visible{    
    display: block;
}

.submenu a.home {

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bpi.png) no-repeat 4px 10px;        
 }



.submenu a.users { 

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bicici.png) no-repeat 4px 10px; 
}

.submenu a.signout { 

    display: inline-block;
    background: url(../imagenes/bai.png) no-repeat 4px 10px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="parent"><a href="#" class="home">Home ></a></li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#" class="home">Home 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="users">Home 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">Home 13</a></li>
      </ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="explore">Explore</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="users"> Users</a></li>
      <li class="parent"><a href="#" class="signout"> Sign Out ></a></li>
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a href="#" class="home">Home 11</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="users">Home 12</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="signout">Home 13</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content">
    <a href="#" data-toggle=".container" id="sidebar-toggle">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cVJsr826FJ8LXFGDIaHoXXAR2TDS-aHY/view
when I click the home button, there are two sub menus that open. one below and one on the side

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("[data-toggle]").click(function () {
    var toggle_el = $(this).data("toggle");
    $(toggle_el).toggleClass("open-sidebar");
});
$('.parent').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.submenu').toggle('visible');
});
```

});

and

```
 <li class="parent"> <ul class="submenu"><li>blablabla</li></li>
```